# Why dynamically updated data in highstock seems not work properly

Tags: dynamic, highcharts

Why I changed the series num to lower amount like 200 or 100 , the navigator seems work not properly?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1exyX.png)

```
for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1)
```

The demo is correct，but if I changed 999 on line 57 to 100 it goes wrong~

[Demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

Comment: The example you gave doesn't have the code related to changing the data. can you update your code with those changes

Comment: I run your example and cannot replicate your issue. The navigator seems to be refreshed.

Comment: Yes,the demo is correct, its official demo, but why i changed 999 to 100 on line 57, the navigator shows different, the first point in navigator doesn‘t change and new added point is always empty.Tks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could force `dataGrouping` in a navigator's series.

```
navigator: { series:{ dataGrouping: { forced: true } } },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qc3avbLo/

[The issue is reported.](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4923)